# How to get list of all files with its complete path in mac

Tags: macos

I want to get list of files present in particular folder along with all its subdirectories. How to achieve this in mac in commandline. I tried by giving ls command but i am not getting complete path

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: I want to include this in my shell script. So i need a command to add in my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following command in command line

```
find "path to the folder" 
ex: find /Users/mahalaxmi/Desktop
```